How to populate a table from a json array column in another table?
In my Postgres database I naively created a column in table Foos as a json[] that looks like this:
TABLE Foos

id | ... | baas
--------------------------------
1  | ... | [
   | ... |   {
   | ... |     "name": "a",
   | ... |     "property": "1",
   | ... |   },
   | ... |   {
   | ... |     "name": "b",
   | ... |     "property": "2",
   | ... |   },
   | ... |   ...
   | ... | ]
2  | ... | [ ... ]
3  | ... | [ ... ]

Now I want to populate table Baas with the items in my json array like this:
TABLE Baas

id | foo_id | name | property 
------------------------------
1  |      1 |    a |        1
2  |      1 |    b |        2 

How can I do this in simple SQL?

Note that the input value indicates type json, not json[].

Use json_populate_record() or json_populate_recordset().
Short, casts to target types implicitly, and fast.
But get your setup and terminology straight!
json[] is a Postgres array of json. While this is totally possible, it's unlikely. Once you work with JSON, you would typically nest a JSON array in the plain Postgres type json.
Depending on what you have exactly, setup and solution are subtly different:
json[]: Postgres array of json
(Less likely.)
Setup
CREATE TABLE foos (
  id int
, baas json[]  -- type json[] - Postgres array of json (??)
);

INSERT INTO foos VALUES
  (1, '{"{\"name\": \"a1\", \"property\": \"1\"}"
       ,"{\"name\": \"b1\", \"property\": \"2\"}"}')    -- pg array with 2 json elements: JSON objects with two properites each
, (2, '{"[{\"name\": \"a2\", \"property\": \"1\"}
         ,{\"name\": \"b2\", \"property\": \"2\"}]"}')  -- pg array with 1 json element: JSON array with 2 objects each, two properites each
;

Wait, that syntax looks confusing! See:

How to pass custom type array to Postgres function

Queries
One of these two:
INSERT INTO baas (foo_id, name, property)
SELECT f.id, b.name, b.property
FROM   foos f, unnest(f.baas) a(baas), json_populate_record(null::baas, a.baas) b
WHERE  f.id = 1;

INSERT INTO baas (foo_id, name, property)
SELECT f.id, b.name, b.property
FROM   foos f, unnest(f.baas) a(baas), json_populate_recordset(null::baas, a.baas) b
WHERE  f.id = 2;

json: scalar type with nested JSON array
(More likely.)
Setup
CREATE TABLE foos (
  id int
, baas json  -- type json (with nested JSON array)
);

INSERT INTO foos VALUES
  (3, '[{"name": "a", "property": "1"}
      , {"name": "b", "property": "2"}]')  -- 1 JSON array with 2 objects, each with 2 properties
;

Query
INSERT INTO baas (foo_id, name, property)
SELECT f.id, b.name, b.property
FROM   foos f, json_populate_recordset(null::baas, f.baas) b;

fiddle

I solved it myself:
INSERT INTO public.baas (foo_id, name, property)
SELECT 
    foo_id,
    array_element ->> 'name',
    (array_element ->> 'property')::integer
FROM (
    SELECT 
        id as foo_id, 
        unnest(baas) AS array_element
    FROM 
        public.foos
) AS subquery_alias;


you can simplify your FROM clause : FROM public.foos CROSS JOIN LATERAL unnest(baas) AS array_element
